# Set geo location manually on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, geolocation, gps

Is there a way I can set the Windows 10 geo location manually? There is little information about this on the web.

Comment: Is this for websites? Do you have a USB GPS?

Comment: it is for windows and I don't.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use a Fake GPS adapter driver to provide a location of your choice.

A quick search shows an [open source one](https://github.com/juliankay/FakeGPS) which, especially looking at the comments [here](https://juliankay.com/development/using-cortana-with-a-fake-gps-driver-on-windows-10/), appears to be the only way people are doing it (I would presume nobody would be making such a driver if it were simple to spoof this information.)

Comment: What is "2. Test Mode Enabled (bcdedit /set testsigning on)" ?

Comment: @Pedro77 It requires an unsigned "test" driver, so Windows needs to be told to boot in 'test' mode. Effectively it allows you to run any driver you want, but I believe it displays a watermark in the corner of the desktop also. It's a command you run in an elevated command prompt, but it does, of course, carry security concerns. Turning it off is the same command but 'off': https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2509241 - I'm not sure on your requirement for this, if it's on a daily driver machine it may be best to avoid for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome press F12 to open console. Go to the three dots for 'more tools' and select sensors where u can edit the Geolocation.

[image: Chrome Geolocation]

Comment: This is helpful to know regarding  browsers, but Windows itself apparently still requires mock GPS driver to override the other ways that windows tries to guess geolocation.

Answer (score 0):

I see that in the Chrome Web Store there is an app called "GPS Link" by cleansoft.lv which purports to let you use your phone's GPS sensor to set location in (windows desktop) chrome. There are endless fake GPS apps for android (and I assume for iOS as well), so putting the two together should give what you want, at least for chrome.

I will try it later this weekend and report here if it works or not. But just in case someone wants to try it before i get to it.

scott

Comment: Answers are intended to be definitive solutions.  Reporting that you spotted something isn't a solution.  After you try it and can report something, that's the time for an answer.

Comment: @fixer1234 better than nothing I guess.

Comment: It might be better than nothing, but then it should be as a comment to the question, not as an answer. One can avoid having a week longer than 7 years...